# Why is urlopen not working for certain websites?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urlopen

I am very new to python and I am trying to webscrape some basic data from a client's website. I have tried this exact same method with other websites and received the expected results. This is what I have so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = 'https://www.grainger.com/category/pipe-hose-tube-fittings/hose-products/hose-fittings-couplings/cam-groove-fittings-gaskets/metal-cam-groove-fittings/stainless-steel-cam-groove-fittings'

uClient = urllib.request.urlopen(main_url)
main_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
```

Even this simple call to read a website is causing what appears to be a timeout error. As I said I have used this exact same code successfully on other websites. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pricing_Tool.py", line 6, in <module>
    uClient = uReq(main_url)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1362, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1322, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Brian Knoll\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Is it possible that this website is just too large to process?
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually websites return a response on sending a request via `requests`. But there are some websites that need some specific headers like User-Agent, Cookie etc. This is one such website. You have send the `User-Agent` so that website sees that the request is coming from a browser. The following code should return response code 200.

```
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
res = requests.get("https://www.grainger.com/category/pipe-hose-tube-fittings/hose-products/hose-fittings-couplings/cam-groove-fittings-gaskets/metal-cam-groove-fittings/stainless-steel-cam-groove-fittings", headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
```

Update:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
print(soup.find_all("a"))
```

This would give all the anchor tags